# Operator norm of a soft thresholded symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, operator-norms

Let $A$ be a symmetric real-valued $n\times n$ matrix and let ${\left\|A\right\|_{2\rightarrow 2}} := \max_{\left\|u\right\|_{2}\leq 1} \left\|Au\right\|_{2}$ denotes its operator norm (largest singular value). Furthermore, for a strictly positive scalar $\lambda$, define the soft thresholding function by

$$f_{\lambda}(x) := (\left\lvert x \right\rvert-\lambda)_{+} \mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(x) =  \max(\left\lvert x \right\rvert-\lambda, 0) \mathop{\mathrm{sign}}(x).$$

Finally, I define the soft thresholded version of $A$ by $A_{\lambda} := \Big[f_{\lambda}(A_{ij})\Big]^n_{i,j=1}$.

Is it true to say that the soft thresholding operation reduces the operator norm, i.e. ${\left\|A_{\lambda}\right\|_{2\rightarrow 2}} \leq {\left\|A\right\|_{2\rightarrow 2}}$. Note that this claim is obviously true for all entry-wise norms such as Frobenius or $\sup$ norms.

I could not find any counter-example for $10^5$ randomly generated Gaussian matrices!

Comment: I don't think so: imagine a large matrix of all 1's with the (1,1) entry replaced by -1.1. The vector corresponding to the largest singular vector will be all positive. Changing -1.1 to -1 increases the norm of the image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The soft thresholding operator shrinks all the entries at the same time, right? So, I don't understand how does you example fits into the framework.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas  Mathematica indicates that for $n=50$ the eigenvalues decrease. Here is the relevant code (N[Eigenvalue[ConstantArray[1,{50,50}]-2.1*SparseArray[{{1,1}->1},{50,50}]]], N[Eigenvalue[ConstantArray[.9,{50,50}]-1.9*SparseArray[{{1,1}->1},{50,50}]]]).

It is certainly true if the entries are all positive (and greater than $\lambda$) in $A$.

Comment: @JosiahPark Yes, the claim is true if all the entries are non-negative. I don't think we need the part regarding greater than $\lambda$. When all the entries are non-negative then all the entries of the leading eigenvector has to be non-negative as well. So, shrinking operation reduces the norm.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake - I thought you were truncating the biggest entries; not reducing them all simultaneously.

Comment: BTW, could you edit your question to clarify that you are indeed talking about real-valued matrices?

Comment: It is true for $n=2$, but it is likely you have already checked the trivial cases.

Comment: @JosiahPark Can you post the proof for $n=2$? It wasn't obvious to me.